# How to obtain the value for the 3rd one from the bottom in bash?

Tags: bash, awk

I have a line like this

3672975 3672978 3672979

`awk '{print $1}'` will return the first number 3672975

If I still want the first number, but indicating it is the 3rd one from the bottom, how should I adjust `awk '{print $-3}'`?

The reason is, I have hundreds of numbers, and I always want to obtain the 3rd one from the bottom.

Can I use `awk` to obtain the total number of items first, then do the subtraction?

Answer (score 2):

`$NF` is the last field, `$(NF-1)` is the one before the last etc., so:

```
$ awk '{print $(NF-2)}'
```

for example:

```
$ echo 3672975 3672978 3672979 | awk '{print $(NF-2)}'
3672975
```

**Edit**:

```
$ echo 1 10 100 | awk '{print $(NF-2)}'
1
```

Comment: I tested your "echo" it works as you said. But on my cluster, it is still 3672977 (3672979-2), not 3672975

Comment: Did you even try it?

Comment: Please describe _on your cluster_ more thoroughly. Are you pasteing that `print` to an existing program? Which Awk are you running and in which kind of environment and how? If that `echo` method works, something else is stoping it from working in your environment.

Comment: I have asked this question to our IT staff, waiting for their reply

Comment: Our IT staff me: I was using $NF-2 not $(NF-2). Finally got it!

Answer (score 1):

or with `cut` and `rev`

```
echo 1 2 3 4 | rev | cut -d' ' -f 3 | rev
2
```

Comment: it works for me now by using rev |awk '{ print $3 }'|rev          Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, did I downvoter your reply? Really sorry about that.